# Spread out data on the histogram matplotlib jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Mind me, I'm new to matplotlib and I am trying to spread out the data in my histogram that can be seen below. Below is the result of what I coded:

[image: my attempt]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: Want to achieve]

I tried spreading out the bins but it only decrease the frequency and not spread out the graph.
Below is my code:

```
#Loading data
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diggledoot/dataset/master/uber-raw-data-apr14.csv'
latlong = pd.read_csv(url)

#Rounding off data for more focused results
n=2
latlong['Lon']=[round(x,n) for x in latlong['Lon']]
latlong['Lat']=[round(x,n) for x in latlong['Lat']]

#Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.title('Rides based on latitude')
plt.hist(latlong['Lat'],bins=100,color='cyan')
plt.xlabel('Latitude')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xticks(np.arange(round(latlong.Lat.min(),1),round(latlong.Lat.max(),1),0.1),rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

How do I space out x-ticks in a similar fashion to the histogram I want to achieve?

Comment: Did you check the 'set_xlim' in matplotlib ? Maybe it can be useful for you.
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim

Comment: You really have only one control with histogram, that is the number of bins.  And a whole bunch of formatting things...  If your histogram is to "peaky" you probably have data out there in the edges.  So you can truncate your dataset (usually bad idea) or tinker with number of bins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
frequency, bins = np.histogram(latlong['Lat'], bins=20)
print(frequency)
print(bins)
```

you get

```
[     1      7     12     18    301  35831 504342  22081   1256    580
     63     12      8      1      2      0      0      0      0      1]
[40.07   40.1725 40.275  40.3775 40.48   40.5825 40.685  40.7875 40.89
 40.9925 41.095  41.1975 41.3    41.4025 41.505  41.6075 41.71   41.8125
 41.915  42.0175 42.12  ]
```

You can see that there are some counts very far away from the mean.

You can ignore those far from mean bins by clipping your variable of interest between a specified min and max and then plot histogram, something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#Loading data
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diggledoot/dataset/master/uber-raw-data-apr14.csv'
latlong = pd.read_csv(url)

#Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.title('Rides based on latitude')
plt.hist(np.clip(latlong['Lat'], 40.6, 40.9),bins=50,color='cyan')
plt.xlabel('Latitude')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

This will yield the following

[image]